# Apply safe filter to concatenated html string

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I have been trying to do this:

```
{% set error_message = '<span class="help-inline">' + field.errors[0]|e + '</span>' %}
{# ... code ... #}
{{ error_message|safe }}
```

Trying to get this output in html:

```html
<span class="help-inline">Some message</span>'
```

However the html is escaped and I get the above printed out as a string.

So question is how to mark a concatenated string as `safe` in Jinja2 ?

---

Current output (firebug):

[image: span as html encoded string]

Expected output:

[image: correct html output]

---

**Update:** Tried this but didn't work:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ error_message|safe }}
    {# also tried without safe #}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Does `{% autoescape false %}` help? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#controlling-autoescaping

Comment: @frb just tried, it doesn't work, any other ideas? see update to how i tried

Comment: No, sorry. I think assignments in Jinja using `set` might be escaped in a way that doesn't respect `|safe` or `autoescape`. That might be a bug.

Comment: @frb alright, i did find a way to do it though, albeit it doesn't look like a good solution. posting it as an answer for now, looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Marking each *part string of the concatenation* as `safe` however gives the desired output:

```
{% set error_message = '<span class="help-inline">'|safe + field.errors[0]|e + '</span>'|safe %}
```

OR slightly better:

```
{% set error_message = ('<span class="help-inline">' ~ field.errors[0]|e ~ '</span>')|safe %}
```

(combined `safe` filter for entire string concatenated with `~` instead. `+` doesn't work for this)